# I'm trying to debug in visual studio code. didn't succeed yet

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I've used the msys64 to download gdb,
my launch.json is looks this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [  
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry":true,
            "cwd":"C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false, 
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true,
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

am I missing anything?
I think the problem is with the program path:

"program": "${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",

when I launch the debug it doesn't stop at break point.
and when i press f5 it open a new folder with a different directory.

And this is my task.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g3",
                "-Wall",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\cpp.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Run C++ Program: g++.exe",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\cpp.exe -g3 -Wall \"${file} -o  \"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\" &&$\"{fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\"",         
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\cpp.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you mean launch.json?  This is visual studio question not really gdb.

Comment: yes, launch.json, is what i meant.

Comment: im not quite sure what kinda question this should be.

Comment: Fix file name in the question.  I don't know anything about visual studio, but others might.  Good luck.  I added the visual-studio tag for you earlier.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure this out.